# Postgresql get first True value for the aggregated variable

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

Let's say I have the following table. Please consider all three versions:

Version 1:

```
Aggr_ID     ID      boolean_value
123         123     False
123         124     True        
123         125     False           
123         126     True
```

Version 2:

```
Aggr_ID     ID      boolean_value
123         123     True
123         124     False       
123         125     False           
123         126     False
```

Version 3:

```
Aggr_ID     ID      boolean_value
123         123     False
123         124     False       
123         125     False           
123         126     False
```

What I would like to get is the following table for cases 1 and 2:

```
Aggr_ID     boolean_value
123         True
```

and the following table for the case no. 3:

```
Aggr_ID     boolean_value
123         False
```

The idea is that if there's at least one `True` in the `boolean_value` column the aggregated ID should be associated with `True`.

I truly don't know how to approach this problem so please excuse me for the lack of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) when you `group by Aggr_ID`:

```
select 
  Aggr_ID, 
  bool_or(boolean_value) boolean_value
from tablename
group by Aggr_ID
```